# Merging rows in SQLite 3

Tags: sqlite, merge

I have the following SQLite 3 table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE rolestats (player TEXT, role TEXT, teamwins SMALLINT, individualwins SMALLINT, totalgames SMALLINT, UNIQUE(player, role));
```

Some sample data:

```
sqlite> SELECT * FROM rolestats WHERE player LIKE "%rika%" LIMIT 10;
rika|jester|0|3|4
rika|guardian angel|0|0|1
rika|clone|0|1|1
rika|village elder|1|0|1
rika|village drunk|7|5|10
rika|cultist|5|0|15
rika|detective|3|2|4
rika|wolf cub|7|3|11
Rika|wolf|0|0|1
Rika|shaman|2|1|2
```

As you can see, the name has different capitalizations. It uses IRC account names, but they can be changed. There are cases when they differ in more than just case, too. For this particular case, case-insensitivity is planned but not something we have yet.

Here's what I've come up with:

```
SELECT role, SUM(teamwins), SUM(individualwins), SUM(totalgames) FROM rolestats WHERE player LIKE "%rika%" GROUP BY role;
```

I've already done this once before, but now I can't figure out how to insert the result of this query into `player = "rika"` and delete the other player name variants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After comment, about the common patterns contained in a name, this should be helpful:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO rolestats
SELECT  'rika',
        role, 
        SUM(teamwins) as teamwins, 
        SUM(individualwins) as individualwins, 
        SUM(totalgames) as totalgames
FROM rolestats WHERE player LIKE '%rika%' group by role;

DELETE FROM rolestats WHERE player != 'rika' AND player LIKE '%rika%';
```

I'm not sure if your approach is correct, it would mean that if you had user names like "MoreRika" and just "rika", they both would be summed up in your stats (because of '%').

I think you want to normalize user name before conversion (e.g. convert it to lower case or capitalise it). Unfortunately SQLite doesn't support updates with sub queries, but `REPLACE` can be used as an alternative.

I think the problem you're trying to solve can be solved like this:

```
-- we convert all non-normalized names to their normalized format
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO rolestats
SELECT  LOWER(player),
        role, 
        SUM(teamwins) as teamwins, 
        SUM(individualwins) as individualwins, 
        SUM(totalgames) as totalgames
FROM rolestats group by LOWER(player), role;

-- now we can delete all non-normalized player names
DELETE from rolestats WHERE player NOT IN (
  SELECT LOWER(rs.player) FROM rolestats rs
);
```

Check out this SQL fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/3d721/2

Note that this single query will convert all users, if you want to convert only specific users, you have to add WHERE clause:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO rolestats
SELECT  LOWER(player),
        role, 
        SUM(teamwins) as teamwins, 
        SUM(individualwins) as individualwins, 
        SUM(totalgames) as totalgames
FROM rolestats WHERE LOWER(player) = 'rika' group by role;

DELETE from rolestats WHERE LOWER(player) = 'rika' AND player != 'rika';
```

Like in this SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/3d721/8

Comment: You're right, but there are other cases where the names share a common pattern (e.g. end in `119`). I always check manually before to make sure I'm not merging someone else's stats, anyway.

Comment: Anyway, thanks! I'll give you the bounty when it allows me to (in 17 hours).

Comment: @nyuszika7h thanks, by the way if you're doing it manually, I'll post in a second updated query. I think in such case you have to pick new common name (the one into which the results will be merged).

Comment: Isn't that basically just `SELECT ... FROM rolestats WHERE player LIKE '%119' GROUP BY role` and `DELETE FROM rolestats WHERE player LIKE '%119' AND player != 'Reaper119'`?

Comment: @nyuszika7h it's INSERT REPLACE, it'll update the rows. Check this out: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/3d721/9. I mean if you only do select, the old rows will be unaffected, and then you'll loose your stats on delete.

Comment: Yes, I got that, I accidentally left that out from my comment. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @nyuszika7h then yes, I think it is basically like that, but also keep in mind that it can merge several player names, if they all end with '119', which I am not sure is what you want. I've updated my answer.